# Create new JSON file from another with some changed values in PHP

Tags: php, json, file

1st JSON file with dictionary. -> dictionary.json

```
Array(
[label] => Name
[options] => Array
    (
        [green] => Value 1
        [blue] => Value 2
        [purple] => Value 3
    ))
```

2nd JSON file with products with all eng names. -> main.json

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [id] => 1
           [cat_id] => 1
           [options] => Array
               (
                   [width] = 100
                   [height] = 100
                   [color] = green
               )
         )
    etc.
)
```

I would like to create a new JSON file that would contain the same data as the 2nd JSON file, plus a translated values for color attribiute.
The script below allows me to change the color to a value from the dictionary, but when writing to a new file the names remain the same - unchanged. Is it possible to write it with changed values?

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('main.json');
$json_dict = file_get_contents('dictionary.json');

$decoded = json_decode($json);
$decoded_dict = json_decode($json_dict);

for($i = 1; $i < count($decoded); $i++){
    
     $temp = $decoded[$i]->options->color;
     $decoded[$i]->options->color = $decoded_dict->options->$temp;
}

$new_json = json_encode($decoded);
file_put_contents("myfile.json", $new_json);
```

Comment: your `for` loop must start from `0` and not from `1` when you use the loop-index as key-identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start your `for loop` from **0** instead **1** because array index starting from **0**:

```php
...
for($i = 0; $i < count($decoded); $i++){
...
```

and I recommend to you that use `foreach loop` ([PHP foreach doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)):

```php
...
foreach($decoded as $d){
    $temp = $d->options->color;
    $d->options->color = $decoded_dict->options->{$temp};
}
...
```